# Identify the list of projects in Artifactory associated with a specific jar file using Fortify

Tags: jar, artifactory, fortify

I have an `Artifactory` with several projects, each having various versions of `.jar` files within.

- How can I use `Fortify` to identify a vulnerability within a specific version of `.jar` file, say `v1.2.1`.

On top of this, I may have several latest versions.

- Since `v1.2.1` is identified to be having a vulnerability with the help of `Fortify`, how to identify the list of projects that internally use this `v1.2.1` `.jar` file using `Fortify` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one of the [Build integrations](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration) (i.e. generate a [buildInfo](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info)) you can either:
 1. Retrieve the BuildInfo json and extract the list of project dependencies from there (also, you can take a look [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin), [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin), and the best option, [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory)). Or,
 2. Use the Artifactory Query Language ([AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language)) to get a list of dependencies used in the project (Build).

p.s I work at JFrog